# Python run a program through a ssh subprocess and get it's stdout while running

Tags: python, ssh, subprocess, stdout, paramiko

I have a python script running an image processing thread and I would like this script to start another script on an other machine. The first script should get data from the image processing thread, send them to the second script and get the stdout from the second script while everything is running.

I succeed to run a program through ssh using spur library. I was able to send data to that program, but not to get it's stdout while it was still running (have to wait the process to finish):

```
    import spur
```

`# Open SSH connection
print("Connection ...")
ssh = spur.SshShell(
    hostname="host",
    username="name",
    password="pswd",
    missing_host_key=spur.ssh.MissingHostKey.accept,
)

# start program in a process (on the second machine)
process = ssh.spawn(["sudo", "python3.6", "program.py"])
c=0
while True:
    print("send data : " + str(c))
    process.stdin_write(str(c))
    c+=1`

I tried to find any information to do it an other way, maybe using an other package (like paramiko ?) but didn't find any applications like that.

Does someone have some information on that ? Should I use totally something else ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you running this code on a linux machine, or windows?

Answer (score 0):

pexpect is good for this sort of thing:

https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pxssh.html

https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect/blob/master/examples/monitor.py

Comment: This is why I asked if he is on Linux. I automate ssh often at work using pexpect, but the last time I checked the windows implementation did not work.

Comment: Indeed it could be nice but I'm on windows. I will better try to open sockets to communicate I think.